# Why precision_recall_fscore_support returns 2 values?

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall

I am using precision_recall_fscore_support for the first time

```
precision, recall, fscore, support = score(y_test, y_pred)


print('precision: {}'.format(precision))
print('recall: {}'.format(recall))
print('fscore: {}'.format(fscore))
print('support: {}'.format(support))
```

But I get 2 values for each

```
precision: [0.67420814 0.67032967]
recall: [0.62343096 0.71764706]
fscore: [0.64782609 0.69318182]
support: [239 255]
```

Why do I have 2 values for each evaluation?

and how I would get the standard precision/recall/f1score?

Comment: if the below answer satisfied you, kindly accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what score exactly you're talking about, I believe it's .score() from sklearn library, if it's so, then below is the answer.

```
Parameters
X : array-like, shape = (n_samples, n_features)
Test samples.
y : array-like, shape = (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
True values for X.
sample_weight : array-like, shape = [n_samples], optional
Sample weights.
**Returns**
score : float
either accuracy or R^2 of self.predict(X) wrt. y.
```

**in you're case I believe you have 2 classes in the o/p, hence it's returning 2 values.
e.x: class1 precision is 0.67420814, class2 is 0.67032967**

here is the link which may help you, https://www.kite.com/python/docs/sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge.score

I suggest you to use classification_report(https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) library, which minimizes you're work.